# Custom Sorting in SQL Server with multiple case statements on same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have the data of one column as (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,17,18) and expected the output after sort as (2,3,18,4,17,5,6,7,8)

I have written code using order by clause as below

`order by case when column = 17 then 5 when column = 18 then 3 else column end asc`

the output from the above order by clause is as (2,3,18,4,5,17,6,7,8)

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remember that ordering between same values will be left to SQL. Plus your clause also defines it as ASC.

So between 3 and 18 which have same value as 3 , because 3 is less than 18 it comes in order 3 followed by 18

Similarly for 17 and 5, 5 comes before 17, so display order is 5 followed by 17.

To correct this change your clause to

`order by case when column = 17 then 4.5 when column = 18 then 3.5 else column end asc`

Comment: Hey Thanks buddy. It is working fine with your suggested change.